# C++Builder TWebBrowser doesn't work with Google OAuth login

Tags: google-oauth, c++builder, twebbrowser

I maintain an application written in C++Builder 2009. Part of it involves using a `TWebBrowser` control (based on Internet Explorer) to send users to a Google login page in order to obtain an OAuth key. This has worked well for a while, but now Google, bless their hearts, has implemented some kind of security upgrade, and now my users get to a page that says "Couldn't sign you in, this browser or app may not be secure". FYI, I am already setting a Registry key that is supposed to make IE run in version 11 emulation mode.

I do have a couple of workarounds: If the user runs IE first in admin mode, signs on, leaves it up while running my application, we don't get the problem. Second, I can start up the default browser - Chrome, IE, whatever - and send them to the URL for OAuth, then it avoids the error message.

The problem with this solution is that without being able to hook into `TWebBrowser` events, I don't have any way to automatically retrieve the OAuth key - it is necessary for the user to cut/paste it into my application. I'd like to avoid these clunky solutions.

I should also mention, this problem occurs only for certain Gmail accounts. I have no idea what the difference is between accounts that work and don't work. Any ideas on that?

So, is there any way to configure IE or `TWebBrowser` so this security issue is bypassed? Or, if I was to update to a modern version of C++Builder and use `TWebBrowser` (or something else?), would this problem be avoided? Any other ideas to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The latest C++Builder supports Google's Chromium engine, it's probably safe to say it'll be compatible with Google's security upgrades.

[Powerful Chromium Based WebView Component To Host Web Content In Your Delphi/C++ Builder FireMonkey Apps](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/powerful-chromium-based-webview-component-to-host-web-content-in-your-delphi-c-builder-firemonkey-apps/)